# Error Starting Diaspora on Debian

Tags: debian, java

I get the following error on debian squeeze unstable when starting the pod:

```
$ bundle exec thin start
>> Using rack adapter
Jammit Warning: Asset compression disabled -- Java unavailable.
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `load': syntax error on line 29, col 2: `  socket_secure: false' (ArgumentError)
```

The full error is at the pastebin.  Any suggestions?

http://pastebin.com/w8HR5H01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a syntax error in the application.yml file, the previous line to the one that was erroring - `socket_secure:` did not have a space betweent the key and value:

```
 ca_file:'/where/it/is'
```

instead of

```
 ca_file: '/where/it/is'
```